# Cannot invoke forEach((<no type> de) -> {}) on the primitive type void

Tags: java, collections, java-8

I Have a list of elements and I want to create a constructor inside a forEach element, but I got the error: **Cannot invoke forEach(( de) -> {}) on the primitive type   void**

```
List<MatchEventMobileApp> matchEventMobileApp 
    = new ArrayList<matchEventMobileApp>();


matchEventService
    .findAllByMatch(“JVT”))
        .sort(Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived))
        .forEach(de -> matchEventMobileApp.add(new MatchEventMobileApp(de)));



public List<MatchEvent> findAllByMatch(Match match) {

        return matchEventRepository.findAllByMatch(match);

    }
```

Comment: My guess is that `findAllByMatch` returns a `List`, and `List#sort(Comparator)` returns `void` because it modifies the list in-place.

Comment: Please add `findAllByMatch` method signature, @Clashsoft is most likely correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `findAllByMatch` method is returning a `List<MatchEvent>`.

And the `List.sort(someComparator)` method returns `void`, i.e. it returns nothing, because it sorts the list in-place. So you can't chain a call to `forEach(someConsumer)`.

One solution to your problem would be to work with a `Stream` instead of a `List`:

```
List<MatchEventMobileApp> matchEventMobileApp = matchEventService
    .findAllByMatch(SOME_MATCH)
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived))
        .map(de -> new MatchEventMobileApp(de)) // or MatchEventMobileApp::new
        .collect(Collectors.toList()); // better collect to a new list instead of
                                       // adding to an existing one within forEach
```

This way, you are now working with a `Stream`, whose `sorted` method returns another `Stream` (a sorted one), on which you can call a *terminal operation*, i.e. `collect`, `forEach`, `anyMatch`, etc.

Another possibility would be to extract the list to a variable and work with it:

```
List<MatchEvent> list = matchEventService.findAllByMatch(SOME_MATCH);

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived));

list.forEach(de -> matchEventMobileApp.add(new MatchEventMobileApp(de)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
List<MatchEventMobileApp> matchEventMobileApp 
    = matchEventService
        .findAllByMatch(“JVT”)
        .stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(MatchEvent::getDateReceived))
        .map(MatchEventMobileApp::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```